# Conditional value in sqlite column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two integer columns in my sqlite table: `a` and `b`. I need to create a third column, `c`, which should contain either `Y` if `a+b mod 2 == 1` or `N` if the previous condition is not satisfied. I am not sure how to define such a column with a conditional value in my query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this readily in a query:

```
select a, b, (case when (a + b) % 2 = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end) as col3
from table t;
```

You can do this in an `update` statement as well:

```
update t
    set col3 = (case when (a + b) % 2 = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end) ;
```

You need to be sure that `col3` exists.  You can do that with `alter table`:

```
alter table t add column col3 int;
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me a clear approach to this! I'll need to get a better grasp of sqlite's capabilities...