# Delete a string after certain symbol SQlite

Tags: string, sqlite

I have a sqlite dictionary database with table called "eng" and column called "defn".
Data in "defn" is like that:

> /(v5r,vt) (uk) to pluck/to pick/to tear off
>
> /(n) (uk) (See ほぞ穴) tenon/cog/dovetail/pivot
>
> /(adj-no) bilingual/in two languages

What I need is to delete all the symbols after first ")".
Result must be something like that:

> /(v5r,vt)
>
> /(n)
>
> /(adj-no)

I was thinking about using the SUBSTR but the problem is that in each line length of word inside the "()" is different. And /(*some word*) exist in each string of the column.

Couldn't someone kindly suggest me the best way to do it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The [instr() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) returns the position in a string:

```
substr(defn, instr(defn, ')') + 1)
```

Comment: Be careful with what happens if there is NO ````)```` on a given row... [It'll only give the first character. CASE is what you need if you want to solve that. E.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711312/conditional-value-in-sqlite-column